# Elegant tuple manipulation suggestions

Tags: python, tuples

I am working with images and pixel positions represented by tuples. I want to check if pixels are next to each other and came up with a working solution. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution than mine. Here is the function I have:

```
def test_neighbors(tup1, tup2):
    neighbors = lambda a, b: [(a + 1, b), (a - 1, b), (a, b + 1), (a, b - 1)]
    list1 = neighbors(tup1[0], tup1[1])
    list2 = neighbors(tup2[0], tup2[1])
    for item in list1:
        if item in list2:
            return True
    return False
```

Again, this code works perfectly, so if this isn't a proper question I am sorry. Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just check the deltas on your coordinate axis

```
def test_neighbors(tup1, tup2):
    x_delta = abs(tup1[0] - tup2[0])
    y_delta = abs(tup1[1] - tup2[1])
    return x_delta + y_delta == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Alessandro idea but using [NamedTuple](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#named-tuples) to make code more readable

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Pixel(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int

def test_neighbors(pix_a, pix_b):
    x_delta = abs(pix_a.x - pix_b.x)
    y_delta = abs(pix_a.y - pix_b.y)
    return x_delta + y_delta == 1

pix1 = Pixel(2,6)
pix2 = Pixel(2,8)
print(test_neighbors(pix1,pix2))

pix3 = Pixel(2,8)
pix4 = Pixel(3,8)
print(test_neighbors(pix3,pix4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def func(tup1, tup2):
    return abs(sum(a[:2]) - sum(b[:2])) == 1
```

Comment: Same as @Alessandro Solbiati answered, but thank you